# POST http://localhost:5000/getData 404 (Not Found) in reactjs nodejs axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, httprequest

I'm new to react and node.js. What I'm trying to do is I made a fake server(running on port 5000) with an API(http://localhost:5000/getData) having harcode value array of object. Now I want to add new object in the API(http://localhost:5000/getData) from react frontend(running on port 3000). and for that I'm using post of axios but when I try to add new object it gives me error like this:

[image]

Kinda confuse why it's givig like that i think i have done everything right?
I'm attaching the relevent code.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))


// Routes 
app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
    res.json([
        {
            "description": "",
            "durationday": "fullday",
            "end": "null",
            "id": 0,
            "location": "",
            "start": "null",
            "title": "",
        },
        {
            "description": "yaaa!",
            "durationday": "absent",
            "end": "10-04-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 1,
            "location": "perth",
            "start": "10-04-2021 12:10:00",
            "title": "holiday",
        },
        {
            "description": "busy",
            "durationday": "fullday",
            "end": "10-22-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 2,
            "location": "melbourne",
            "start": '10-19-2021 12:00:00',
            "title": "working",
        },
        {
            "description": "dd",
            "durationday": "halfday",
            "end": "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            "id": 3,
            "location": "updated perth",
            "start": "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            "title": "updated holiday",
        }
    ]);
});



app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Running on pot 5000"))
```

**React axios function**

```
const sendData = async () => {
        const post = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/getData', {

            description: "dd",
            durationday: "halfday",
            end: "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            id: parseInt(344444),
            location: "updated perth",
            start: "10-24-2021 12:10:00",
            title: "updated holidayssssssssss",

        }
        )
            .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));

        return post;
    }
```

**onClick button**

```
 <button onClick={sendData}> button post</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your route is set up as a `get` but you’re sending a `post`.

```js
app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
```

```js
const post = await axios.post(
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, actually i wanted to add new object in the same API so for that do I have to make another API in my server.js?

Comment: If you want to handle both GET and POST requests at the same url you have to [set it up to do that](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). The way you have it now your server is only listening for GET requests.

Comment: thanks for replying, now i'm using the axios.all method and it gives me the response 200 but it's not adding the new object. Is it cause I'm mutation the real object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your server code, as provided, returns a hard-coded array of data. No reason to expect it to add anything.

Comment: ok so i the mutating the array of object is not the issue I guess but why it's not adding the new object that I'm trying to send from react with post method, any idea?

Comment: I don’t see any code that adds a new object.

Answer (score 0):

you did `getDate` by `GET`, but call it by `POST`.